# Java Method and Description

Tags: java, methods

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

To the table that begins with "Method Summary",
I understand what the modifier and type means but for the method and description, I'm not understanding what it's saying.  Can someone explain to me in human terms and show an example of how this is used?

Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: Your going to have to specify which one you're talking about; the link goes to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more general terms, the "Method Summary" table you are referring to shows all the methods that are available in the given class. The column "Modifier and Type" specifies what the method returns and what kinds of modifiers (e.g. static, final, etc.) are used with that method.

The "Method and Description" column contains the method names and their description.

For example:

If the table shows the following data (example from your link):

**Modifier & Type**: `String`
**Method and Description**: `getName()`
Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname.

Then the actual method available in an instance of `java.io.File` is:

```
public String getName() {...}
```

What this method does is mentioned in the description part i.e, "Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname". That is, you can call this method from any instance of the `File` class like:

```
File file = new File("some_file");
String name = file.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method and description signifies about the method.

For example:  canExecute() is a method name which is part of **File** class.It can be found at java.io.File.canExecute().

The return type of the method is boolean which may be true/false.

You can refer to the link for example :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_canexecute.htm